# Pandas: Concat adds a row unexpectedly

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm using Pandas with a DataFrame called `df`.  I'm extracting new features with it and combining the resulting two new dataframes with `pd.concat`.  Here's my function:

```
def get_processed_df(df, rare_cols, threshold=10):
    print("df at start", df.shape)

    df = df[pd.notnull(df["FullDescription"]) &  
            pd.notnull(df["Title"]) & 
            pd.notnull(df["SalaryNormalized"])]
    print("df after filtering nulls", df.shape)

    tfidf_desc = get_tfidf_df(df, 
                              "FullDescription", 
                              max_features=100, 
                              prefix="DESC", 
                              tokenize=tokenize)
    print("tfidf_desc shape: ", tfidf_desc.shape)

    tfidf_title = get_tfidf_df(df, 
                               "Title", 
                               max_features=100, 
                               prefix="TITLE", 
                               tokenize=tokenize)
    print("tfidf_title shape: ", tfidf_title.shape)

    df.drop("FullDescription", inplace=True, axis=1)
    df.drop("Title", inplace=True, axis=1)

    final_df = pd.concat([df, tfidf_desc, tfidf_title], axis=1)
    print("final df shape: ", final_df.shape)

    return final_df
```

When I run this, I get the following output:

```
df at start (10000, 12)
df after filtering nulls (9999, 12)
tfidf_desc shape:  (9999, 100)
tfidf_title shape:  (9999, 100)
final df shape:  (10000, 210)
```

So my filtering has removed one row in my original `df` and both `tfidf_desc` and `tfidf_title` dataframes have 9,999 rows also.  I concatentate them with `pd.concat` using `axis=1` and somehow end up with a DataFrame of 10,000 rows, with NaNs for all of the "Title" and "FullDescription" based features.

Any idea why this is happening?

Thanks!

Comment: I suggest you make some better code formatting in the futur. This is unreadable (or hardly readable) at the moment. Zen of python says : "Sparse is better than dense. Readability counts."

Comment: A shorter way to write `pd.notnull(df["FullDescription"]) & pd.notnull(df["Title"]) & pd.notnull(df["SalaryNormalized"])` is `df[['FullDescription', 'Title', 'SalaryNormalized']].notnull().all(1)`.

Comment: You should try to make a small code snippet that reproduces the problem, if you could print the `df.head()` for all three dataframes just before the concat, it would help

Answer (score 3):

After filtering, the index is not reset. This cause an issue when concatening the dataframes. Try this after you filter `df`:

```
df= df.reset_index(drop=True)
```

Comment: Thanks. This fixed me a similar issue I was having